# Making a pie chart from Pandas with custom categories

Tags: python, pandas

First time asker apologies if answered elsewhere and I just can't find it.

I have a dataframe that has some percent values in one column, I want to group all the data that's <1%, 1-2%, 2-5%, 5-10%, and >10% and make a pie chart with those values. I have a column in my dataframe that tells me which "bin" each row goes into (df["Percent"]).

I found

```
percents = df["Percent"].value_counts()
percents

N/A           127
<±1%          28
±5-10%        14
>±10%         14
±1-2%         13
±2-5%         12
Name: Percent, dtype: int64
```

which gets me the info I need, but cannot for the life of me get the data into a piechart (except for just copying the data by hand which would be silly).

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas [`plot.pie`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#pie-plot) and use `labeldistance` and `rotatelabels` to place the categories inside the chart giving the impression that those are the percentages values calculated by the pie chart function.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1245)
d = {
    'Percent': np.random.choice(['N/A', '<±1%', '±1-2%', '±2-5%', '±5-10%', '>±10%'],
                     size=208, p=[0.6105,0.1346,0.0625,0.0578,0.0673,0.0673])
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

percents = df["Percent"].value_counts()
print(percents)

percents.plot.pie(labeldistance=0.5, rotatelabels=True)
plt.show()
```

```py
N/A       137
<±1%       22
±5-10%     14
>±10%      14
±1-2%      13
±2-5%       8
Name: Percent, dtype: int64
```

[image]